# Adding opencpn repository - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'people'

Tags: python, add-apt-repository

When I try to add the opencpn repository I get the following error message:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:opencpn/opencpn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 362, in <module>
    sys.exit(0 if addaptrepo.main() else 1)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 345, in main
    shortcut = handler(source, **shortcut_params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/shortcuts.py", line 40, in shortcut_handler
    return handler(shortcut, **kwargs)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 86, in __init__
    if self.lpppa.publish_debug_symbols:
       ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 126, in lpppa
    self._lpppa = self.lpteam.getPPAByName(name=self.ppaname)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 113, in lpteam
    self._lpteam = self.lp.people(self.teamname)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'people'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: here is a link to the open cpn manual.
https://opencpn.org/wiki/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=opencpn:opencpn_user_manual:getting_started:opencpn_installation:linux and.
https://www.opencpn.org/wiki/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=opencpn:opencpn_user_manual:getting_started:opencpn_installation:ubuntu_ppa also which Ubuntu install are you using as the cpn ppa is only available for LTS versions ...

Comment: This is tricky. Since versions change, it is ultimately important to state your Ubuntu version. With your "record" I would've  expected that from you.

Comment: I got this error when trying to add the deadsnakes PPA on debian 12 i.e. `add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa`. The [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1481830/409682) below fixed it.

Answer (score 21):

Install [python3-launchpadlib](https://help.launchpad.net/API/launchpadlib)

> launchpadlib is an open-source Python library that lets you treat the HTTP resources published by Launchpad's web service as Python objects responding to a standard set of commands. With launchpadlib you can integrate your applications into Launchpad without knowing a lot about HTTP client programming.

> Installation
>
> The launchpadlib in Ubuntu (easy to install)
>
> If you have the latest version of Ubuntu then to install the launchpadlib available in the Ubuntu repositories, open a terminal and run the command:
>
> ```
> $ sudo apt-get install python3-launchpadlib
> ```
>
> And you are done!
>
> If you have an older version of Ubuntu then parts of the instructions below may not work with the version from the repositories but you should be able to install the latest version of launchpadlib manually.

Found on these 2 links: [1](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/debian-bullseye-sid-add-apt-repository-not-working-python-problem-4175720821/), [2](https://groups.google.com/g/linux.debian.bugs.dist/c/iWMiMej6YE0)